# Selecting a field in a loop?

Tags: jquery

```
var listItems = $("#questions .question");
    listItems.each(function(idx, li) {

        //get the question


    });
```

The above selects each li, in each li I have an input with id of "questionField". How can I select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var listItems = $("#questions .question");
listItems.each(function(idx, li) {

    //get the question
    $qf = li.find('#questionField');

});
```

Comment: How can a loop within a loop while searching for an unique id be the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var listItems = $("#questions .question");
listItems.each(function(idx, li) {

     $(li).find("#questionField").text(); // return the question text

});
```

EDIT: it depends on **li** type as well. If it is a jquery object or simple dom. Add more details please

Comment: @user1013512 If you can share your code is a jsFiddle we can answer quite precisely

Comment: Why you want to loop trough the full list if you use `find()` to search for the item? You can just use `$('#questions li').find('#questionField').text()`

Comment: The answer is very precise, so I preferred to answer without completely change initial code. Sure it could be optimized, but I just  answered the question as it is

Comment: So your statement is: `if it works, its ok`? In your example you loop in a loop. This make the script very slow.

Comment: You are right, it is not so efficient.
I just answer the question exactly as it is written, because I didn't know if wanted do other stuff within the first loop or not